# Change certain categorical variables to a unified entry

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, categorical-data

Let's say I have have a dataframe with a column called animals. The entries look as followed:

```
'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I'.
```

I want to change the entries 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H' and 'I' to another unified entry called 'D'. What is the best way to transform all these categorical entries into one category?

Comment: What did you try ? We cannot just give you a snippet of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `list` of the entries you want to change, and then you can assign 'D' for them using `loc` to spot them, and `isin` to evalute if your condition is satisfied:

```
li = ['E','F','G','H','I']
df.loc[df.animals.isin(li), 'animals'] = 'D'
```

An alternative to `loc`, would be `numpy`'s [`where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['animals'] = np.where(df['animals'].isin(li),'D',df['animals'])
```

Which reads: *for every row in the animals column, check if the value is in the the list called `li` and if it is return 'D', otherwise keep the column intact*